# Enable accelerated OpenGL on Windows 8 with NVIDIA Quadro FX 1800M

Tags: windows-8, drivers, opengl, hardware-acceleration, nvidia-quadro

I have a HP EliteBook 8540w with a NVIDIA Quadro FX 1800M graphics card. After installing Windows 8 (64-bit), the following graphics driver has been installed:

```
NVIDIA Quadro FX 1800M (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.2)
Driver Provider: NVIDIA
Driver Date: 21.06.2012
Driver Version: 9.18.13.286
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows
```

It's working just fine, *except* for the fact that it doesn't provide any accelerated OpenGL pixel format, that is, OpenGL is rendered using the generic Windows renderer.

Can anyone point me to a solution to install enable hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: I've found and installed the following beta driver:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-310.34-beta-driver.html

And now OpenGL renderes accelerated.